# Object creation from existing object

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Why the output of the below program is 200-200? Here just changing the object2 member variable value.

```
class X
{
private:
   int *m_plnt;

public:
   X():m_plnt(new int()){}
   X(const X & rhs)
   {
      m_plnt = rhs.m_plnt;
   }
   void setvalue(int value) { *m_plnt = value; }

   int getvalue(){return *m_plnt;}
};

int main()
{
   X obj1;
   obj1.setvalue(100);
   X obj2(obj1); 
   obj2.setvalue(200); // how its changing obj1.m_plnt value
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what pointers are and how they work?

Comment: Because you're setting its value to 200? Also you need a destructor to delete your pointer

Comment: Take a look at C pointer examples. That should clarify it

Answer (score 2):

> Why the output of the below program is 200-200?

Because you only have one integer, and two pointers to it.

> Here just changing the object2 member variable value.

No, you're not changing the member variable; you're changing the value that it points to. Both classes contain a pointer to the same integer. You could see this more clearly without the classes; it's exactly the same as

```
int * p1 = new int();  // Create an integer
*p1 = 100;
int * p2 = p1;         // Point to the same integer
*p2 = 200;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make a copy of obj1 you are taking a copy of the pointer, so obj1 and obj2 are pointing to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

The class definition contains data member that has type of pointer to int. During using the copy constructor the value of this pointer is copied from the original object to the creeated one. So both objects have pointers that refer to the same memory address that is the two objects share the same memory location. And the output of the program demonstrates this fact.
You could change the copy constructor such a way that new memory were allocated. For example

```
X(const X & rhs) : m_plnt(new int(*rhs.m_plnt)) { }
```

In this case the new object has its own allocated memory and changes of the original object would not influence on the new object.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. The second point of allocating new memory is cool.

Comment: @roy Allocating memory is not cool, it requires you to remember to delete it which is easily overlooked. Far better to not use pointers at all

Comment: @David I got your point. I just appreciated the fact that this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

as everyone's already mentioned, you're using pointers, so when you call your copy constructor, all you're actually doing is assigning the address of `rhs.m_plnt` to the address of `this.m_plant`. this means that any changes to either object will result in changes to the other.

also, seeing as you don't seem to need a dynamic array of integers, there's no need for the pointer whatsoever. take a look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
private:
   int m_plnt;

public:
   X():m_plnt(int()){}
   X(const X & rhs)
   {
      m_plnt = rhs.m_plnt;
   }
   void setvalue(int value) { m_plnt = value; }

   int getvalue(){return m_plnt;}
};

int main()
{
   X obj1;
   obj1.setvalue(100);
   X obj2(obj1); 
   obj2.setvalue(200); // how its changing obj1.m_plnt value
   std::cout << obj1.getvalue() << "-" << obj2.getvalue() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

this will output:

`100-200`